# Regular expression for 7 digits not starting with 0 or 1

Tags: regex

I am trying to accept only 7 digit long number not starting with 0 or 1

7089097 - OK

0089097 - Not good

1089097 - Not good

This is what i tried:

```
^\[2-9][0-9]{7}$
```

And not working:)

Comment: If you have not used it before, you can use [this online tool](http://regexr.com?3731h) for checking regexs.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This regex will work:

```
^[2-9][0-9]{6}$
```

Out of 7 digits 1 is consumed by first position `2-9` and then next 6 digits can be from `0-9`

Answer (score 5):

You can try this:

```
^[2-9][0-9]{6}$
```